# Does Einstein's Relativity contradict the Arrow of Time?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, entropy, arrow-of-time

If according to Einstein spacetime is relative & not absolute, and the order of events can change depending on the observer's frame of reference, does this contradict the idea of the Arrow of Time/2nd Law of Thermodynamics (that events must always be ordered in order of increasing entropy)?

For example, suppose from one frame of reference, there is increasing entropy in a sequence of events as time passes. But from another frame of reference, the same sequence of events is in order of decreasing entropy as time passes. Does this mean that from the second perspective, the Arrow of Time/2nd Law is violated?

Comment: The fact that Einstein's Special Theory of Relativity keeps intact a concept of causality so that the arrow of time is still well-defined, is a topic that is covered well in textbooks and emphasised.

Comment: *" But from another frame of reference, the same sequence of events is in order of decreasing entropy as time passes."* Do you have an example for this? Lorentz transformations can only change the temporal order of *spacelike* separated events, which cannot causally affect each other.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know that there was a connection between Causality and Entropy/Arrow of Time...

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I tend to disagree. In my experience, if there is anything emphasized and covered well in textbooks on this subject, it is the fact that in $all$ laws of physics (except the Second Law of Thermodynamics) there is no distinction between past and future.  The only thing that Einstein's relativity says is that there is no possible causal relationship between two events separated by a space-like interval.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Within the analogy of the Arrow of Time, relativity only tells one the direction of its shaft; it doesn't know where the tip/fletching should be. Only the Second Law does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, Einstein's Theory of Relativity does not contradict the notion of "Arrow of Time".

The concept of "Arrow of Time" means that time, contrary to the other physical dimensions, is not isotropic, as one direction (forward) is inherently different than the other one (backward). A good way to measure/describe how the two directions are different is entropy: never increasing backward in time, never decreasing forward in time.

An important concept in the Theory of Relativity is the past and future [light cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone), two subsets of spacetime, meeting at a single event $HN$ (the "here and now"), identifying all the events that could affect $HN$ (past) and all the events that could be affected by $HN$ (future). They are two different sets, and will never be mixed/swapped in any reference frame: if someone measures event $A$ to be in the future light cone of $B$, then no other observer can state that $A$ is in $B$'s past light cone.$^1$

This does not mean that the Arrow of Time is "built-in" the Theory of Relativity. I could take a Relativity textbook, consistently substitute all the words "past" with "future" and vice-versa, and you wouldn't notice. It just means that (like most other theories) it does not say anything against or in favor of the Arrow of Time, and also that (like not many other theories) has a well-defined notion of past and future, albeit consistently swappable.

---

$^1$: what's true is that some observer may measure event $A$ to be outside of any of $B$'s light cones, but still this does not mean that "past and future are inverted".

Answer (score 2):

Causality is conserved in special relativity.
If $|s_{12}|^2= c^2 ((t_1-t_2)^2-(\tilde{r_1}-\tilde{r_2})^2 )$,
then if $ |s_{12}|^2>0 $ the events are causally connected as $v<c$. Through a simple calculation using the transformation rule you can show that once an event is casually connected in one frame it will be causally connected in all other frames, i.e. $s_{12}^2$ remains $>0 $ in all other frames. So it isn't correct that the order of events changes in special relativity.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd Law of Thermodynamics says that for any closed system, its entropy always increases with time.

Now, a closed system is composed of various particles. And thus, the future version of that closed system has the same bunch of particles which it had in the past.

Because the particles composing a closed system cannot travel faster than the speed of light, the future version of the closed system will fit entirely into a "light cone" of the past version of the closed system.

And because within a light cone, causality/temporal ordering of events is preserved, thus the future version of the closed system will indeed always have a higher entropy than the past version, regardless of the the frame of reference.

Answer (score 1):

The passing from non-relativistic physics to Special Relativity does not change any of this. It's not relative in Relativity, there's an absolute relation there, too. It's just different.

Rather: it is the logic of time that is changed.

In the world of non-relativistic physics, the past and future of any event is independent of the event's location. The absolute structure contained in non-relativistic physics are the [3D hyper-]planes of simultaneity. This is the locus of all events that are simultaneous with a given event.

The past of a given event is everything that lies before its plane of simultaneity, the future of the event is everything that lies after the plane. The boundary between the two is the plane, itself: the 3D snapshot of space at the same instant as the event.

In non-relativistic physics all finite non-zero speeds are relative. Infinite speed, however - which is the speed of being simultaneous - is absolute.

Not so in Special Relativity. There: the absolute speed is a finite non-zero speed. Infinite speed, in contrast, is a relative speed. To a moving observer, an infinite speed appears as a finite (faster than light) speed. Simultaneity is, therefore, relative.

The plane of simultaneity is replaced by the past and future light cones.

The future light cone of an event is the locus of all light-speed trajectories that emanate from the place and time of that event. The past light cone of an event is the locus of all light-speed trajectories that converge onto that event. For instance, the sky is the past light cone of your eyeballs at each instant you look up at it.

There's a slightly different sky at each instant, so each eyeball-instant has a slightly different past light cone; and the left and right eyeballs have slightly different past light cones - which would allow you to see in 3D, if you could triangulate distances that far. You can't actually. The best you can do is triangulate clouds up to maybe 1000 meters. I can directly see the 3D'ness of low-hanging clouds, for instance.

In Special Relativity, the past and future of an event depend not just on *when* the event is, but *where*. The past of an event is everything that lies on and before the past light cone of the event. The future of the event is everything that lies on and after the future light cone of the event.

Everything else is in the Absolute Elsewhere of the event. Unlike the case of non-relativistic physics, it's not a 3D snapshot, but an entire 4D continuum - the entire 4D continuum of spacetime that is outside of both light cones. It's the locus of all faster-than-light-speed motions emanating to and from the event - including the infinite speed ones.

So, for instance, at each instant here and now on Earth, there is about 2 1/2 to 3 second interval of the moon's timeline that is **neither** before nor after here and now.

Or ... more to the point ... since Betelgeuse is about 500 light years away, there is a 1000 year long interval of Betelgeuse's timeline that is neither before nor after now. Since Betelgeuse's death is almost certainly less than 500 years away, that means that there's no part of Betelgeuse left in our future. Yet, Betelgeuse's death is **still not** in our past. It's neither past nor future of here and now.

Events that are in the Absolute Elsewhere of one another have no causal connection and there can be no communication between them. Any information-sharing that exists between such events must, therefore, be randomized and scrambled. Quantum theory allows for entanglement between events in one another's Absolute Elsewhere. So, such events can be made to agree on a dice roll, for instance, but can't have any agency in determining the outcome of the dice roll.

That might even be the case on entropy grounds. There is a [No Communication Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem) in Quantum Theory; and I think it might actually be possible to argue it on entropy grounds, in just the way your question suggests.

So, non-relativistic physics and Special Relativity have different temporal logics. You can go further actually formulate *all* of space-time geometry (including defining *spatial* geometric relations) solely from the temporal logic of Special Relativity. That was discovered by A. A. Robb in 1914 [A Theory Of Space And Time](https://archive.org/details/theoryoftimespac00robbrich). So, in Special Relativity, space is effectively just a sideways extension of time.

When it comes to General Relativity, the situation is more involved. Event horizons are the envelopes of light cones - not just the event horizons of black holes, but the effective event horizon that is associated with someone in uniform acceleration. In General Relativity, you can associate a *temperature* with the strength of gravity in the vicinity of an event horizon, and an *entropy* with the area of the event horizon; and that includes the horizons associated with accelerating observers as well.

The conversion between the two is a certain multiple of the Planck Area is equal to one bit of information associated with the entropy. These properties arise out of quantum theory and are linked to such things as the [Bekenstein Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound) and [Unruh-Davies Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect).

In fact, you could actually go one step further and **derive** Einstein's law of gravity from a combination of the First Law Of Thermodynamics and the Second Law Of Thermodynamics, with a suitably defined conversion factor for gravity versus temperature, and horizon area versus entropy. [The Thermodynamics Of Spacetime: The Einstein Equation Of State](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9504004).

The arguments used to derive the no communication theorem for quantum theory in the setting of Special Relativity might have a connection to those used to derive these quantum properties in the setting of General Relativity. But, I'm not sure.